# Unable to route from Azure to On prem

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

we are setting up our VWAN in azure and have got a bit stuck, here is what we have done so far:

Create VWAN, create, VHUB, create VPN, Create address space in Azure, created subnet, Create a VM, Created an NSG. Attempt to contact on prem.

1. The VPN appears to be up, it's connected to the hub successfully
2. The VM can ping through to the private address space in the VHUB
3. The routing shows the next hop as the VHUB private address space
4. We have allowed ICMP in and out on the NSG
5. If we try to ping the on prem network it times out and same from on prem to the VM

It seems we are missing something simple to get the last hop over the VPN. I can see that the next hop is defined with our on PREM IP range. These private address spaces are configured in the VPN.

Is there anything glaringly obvious that we are missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok we have managed to get the cloud VM to talk to (and RDP to) an on prem server. We can't seem to get RDP to work to the cloud VM though. The NSG allows 3389 both ways

Comment: Can you ping both ways?

Comment: I cannot ping either way but I think that is not making it through the VWAN. The NSG allows it but it doesn't work either way. I can do a test-netconnection to an onsite server on port 3389 but not from an on prem machine to the internal IP of the azure machine

Comment: what is the onprem network device?

Comment: It's a cisco firepower

Comment: So, does that mean nobody knows or have I tagged this incorrectly thereby getting the wrong experience base?